# How to find out the no. of components there in JSF?

Tags: jsf-2, components, jstree

Since JSF is a stateful serverside component framework, size of the component tree matters.
The more components on a view, the more time is spent on instantiation, validation 
and rendering.

***How to know how many components are on every view of your application 
and what will be the impact on performance?.***

I came across [JSFInspector](http://tasel.github.io/jsfinspector/index.html#get-started), which helps to investigate this issue. JSFInspector is used during development time. It comes as handy JAR file, no special IDE or plugin required.

```
JSFInspector creates an overview of the lifecycle phases. The overview features the 
duration and status of each lifecycle phase. It offers an easy way to find out which 
phase was completed or if validation did fail. It is especially useful to find bugs 
related to the immediate attribute in views with complex component structures.
```

But I am not able to configure it properly. If anyone has gone through this particular tool, kindly guide me to the workable conditions. The author doesn't mentions which particular jar to be downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through ***JavaServer Faces 2.0, The Complete Reference*** by Ed Burns, Chris Schalk, 
which gives insight into what really UIComponents are, i cam across this,

```
<h:head>
    <title>A Simple JavaServer Faces Registration Application</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h2>JSF Registration App</h2>
        <h4>Registration Form</h4>

        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td><h:inputText label="User First Name" id="fname"
                        value="#{userBean.firstName}" required="true" /> 
                        <br/>
                    <h:message for="fname" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td><h:inputText label="User Last Name" id="lname"
                        value="#{userBean.lastName}" required="true" /> 
                    <h:message for="lname" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sex:</td>
                <td><h:selectOneRadio label="Sex" id="sex"
                        value="#{userBean.sex}" required="true">
                        <f:selectItem itemLable="Male" itemValue="male" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLable="Female" itemValue="female" />
                    </h:selectOneRadio> 
                    <h:message for="sex" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date of Birth:</td>
                <td><h:inputText label="User Date of Birth" id="dob"
                        value="#{userBean.dob}" required="true">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM-dd-yy" />
                    </h:inputText> (mm-dd-yy) 
                    <h:message for="dob" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email Address:</td>
                <td><h:inputText label="User Email Address" id="email"
                        value="#{userBean.email}" required="true"
                        validator="#{userBean.validateEmail}" /> 
                    <h:message for="email" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Service Level:</td>
                <td><h:selectOneMenu label="Service Level"
                        value="#{userBean.serviceLevel}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Medium" itemValue="medium" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Basic" itemValue="basic" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Premium" itemValue="premium" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>
            <h:messages />
        </p>
        <p>
            <h:commandButton value="Register" action="confirm" />
        </p>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

To get the exact make up of the component tree, one has to implement a PhaseListener which gets invoked after the ***PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE*** phase.

```
public class PrintComponentTree implements PhaseListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int indent = 0;
    public static final int INDENTSIZE = 2;


    private void printComponentTree(UIComponent component) {
        printComponentInfo(component);

        List<UIComponent> complist = component.getChildren();
        if (complist.size() > 0)
            indent++;
        for (int i = 0; i < complist.size(); i++) {
            UIComponent uicom = (UIComponent) complist.get(i);
            printComponentTree(uicom);
            if (i + 1 == complist.size())
                indent--;
        }

    }

    public void printComponentInfo(UIComponent comp) {

        if (comp.getId() == null) {
            System.out.println("UIViewRoot" + " " + "("
                    + comp.getClass().getName() + ")");
        } else {
            printIndent();
            System.out.println("|");
            printIndent();
            System.out.println(comp.getId() + " " + "("
                    + comp.getClass().getName() + ")");
        }
    }

     public void printIndent(){
            for (int i=0; i<indent; i++ )  
              for (int j=0;j<INDENTSIZE; j++)  
                System.out.print(" ");          
          }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }

    public PrintComponentTree() {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("(Rendering Component Tree)");
        printComponentTree(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot());

    }
```

[image: ***O/P***]

```
(Rendering Component Tree)
    |
    j_id1 (javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot)
      |
      j_idt1 (com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions)
      |
      j_idt2 (javax.faces.component.UIOutput)
        |
        j_idt3 (com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions)
      |
      j_idt4 (javax.faces.component.UIOutput)
        |
        j_idt5 (javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm)
          |
          j_idt6 (com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions)
          |
          fname (javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText)
          |
          j_idt7 (com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions)
          |
          j_idt8 (javax.faces.component.html.HtmlMessage)
          |
          j_idt9 (com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions)
          |
          lname (javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText)
          |
          j_idt10 (javax.faces.component.html.HtmlMessage)
          |
          j_idt11 (com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions)
          |
          sex (javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneRadio)
            |
            j_idt12 (javax.faces.component.UISelectItem)
            |
            j_idt13 (javax.faces.component.UISelectItem)
          |
          j_idt14 (javax.faces.component.html.HtmlMessage)
          |
          j_idt15 (com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions)
          |
          dob (javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText)
          |
          j_idt16 (com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions)
          |
          j_idt17 (javax.faces.component.html.HtmlMessage)
          |
          j_idt18 (com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions)
          |
          email (javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText)
          |
          j_idt19 (javax.faces.component.html.HtmlMessage)
          |
          j_idt20 (com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions)
          |
          j_idt21 (javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneMenu)
            |
            j_idt22 (javax.faces.component.UISelectItem)
            |
            j_idt23 (javax.faces.component.UISelectItem)
            |
            j_idt24 (javax.faces.component.UISelectItem)
          |
          j_idt25 (com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions)
          |
          j_idt26 (javax.faces.component.html.HtmlMessages)
          |
          j_idt27 (com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions)
          |
          j_idt28 (javax.faces.component.html.HtmlCommandButton)
          |
          j_idt29 (com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions)
      |
      j_idt30 (com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions)
```